# Replace image with text using onmouseover jQuery

Tags: c#, onmouseover, onmouseout

I want to replace an image with a text from label through jQuery (onmouseover and onmouseout). Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_css_image_overlay_slidebottom

Remove from style the following:

```
.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

add this script in the head after the end tag of style:

This is the full answer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container").mouseover(function(){
   var hiddenText = $("#labelid").text();
$(".text").text(hiddenText);
$(".overlay").css("height", "100%");
 });
  $(".container").mouseout(function(){
$(".overlay").css("height", "0%");
 });
});
</script>
```

And then html/css :

```
<label id="labelid" style="display: none;"> myText
 </label>
<div class="container">
 <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
 <div class="overlay">
<div class="text">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i use the label text in your example. Note that, i'm assigning the value in code behind to the label ( asp.met control ) so how can i show it is value in your example @mdln97

Comment: you need to show me what you concretely have, I am not sure about what label text you are talking

Comment: in code behind - NewAccountsLabel.Text = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();   and I have the label defined as <asp:Label ID="NewAccountsLabel" runat="server"  style="display:none;">. so in overlay how can I have the text of NewAccountsLabel @mdln97

Comment: Well just add class=“overlay” for your label and then try getting its text you could do it with innerHtml in plain JS or html() or text() using jQuery

Comment: can I do it as below ? because I did not get any effect :)

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".container").mouseover(function () {
                var hiddenVar = $('[id$="NewAccountsLabel"]').html();
                $(".overlay").css("opacity", "1");
                $(".overlay").text(hiddenVar);
                
               
            });
            $(".container").mouseout(function () {
                $(".overlay").css("opacity", "0");
            });
        });

Comment: in order to get the text of an element with an id in jQuery you do $("#idname").text(), then to adjust the text of another element, like overlay it will be something like $(".overlay").text("sometext"); which should be done before you set the opacity to 1